# fancyhdr and the MastersDoctoralThesis template

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a Miktex 2.9 installation on my computer, I am writing my PhD thesis and I am struggling with the fancyhdr package. Up to now, whenever I need a new package, the software just ask me whether I want to download and install it, I agree with him and I keep going with my thesis.

Problems come with the fancyhdr package. If I add the line of code

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

on my thesis preamble than what I get is

```
! Class MastersDoctoralThesis Error: Package `fancyhdr' is incompatible
(MastersDoctoralThesis)              with this class.

See the MastersDoctoralThesis class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.58 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

?
```

I had a look around, other people struggle with this packages and I also tried to provide a kind of manual download from the Miktex Package Manager, which also "believe" the fancyhdr is already installed. But I can't use it at all.

Would you be able to help me sorting out this problem, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The message says all: you cannot use `fancyhdr` with that class. Can you point to the source of the class and specify what changes to the headers or footers you wish?

Comment: What also helps is the documentation for your class. `texdoc MastersDoctoralThesis` would in most cases pop up the documentation.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Actually not in this case as you'll find the "documentation" (template) online only...

Comment: If you would have typed `h`, there would have been a more meaningful explanation. The template you are using uses package `scrlayer-scrpage` from the KOMA-script bundle.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell this is hardcoded in the MastersDoctoralThesis.cls

```
\ifbool{headsepline}{\KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}}{}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\ClassError{\classname}{Package `fancyhdr' is
incompatible\MessageBreak with this class}{The pagesyles are defined 
using package `scrlayer-scrpage', please consult the\MessageBreak 
KOMA-script documentation for details.}]{fancyhdr}
```

So why not go ahead and checkout the suggested package [scrlayer-scrpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage). Maybe it has the options you need? Checkout chapter 5, especially pg. 236.

E.g. this puts your page pagenumber in the bottom center:

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{- \pagemark{} -}
```

Comment: It looks like scrlayer-scrpage works on my thesis. What I personally need is just to move the page number from the top left to the bottom centre. I am googling around but still I didn't find anything valid and/or easy to apply. Could you suggest me anything?

Comment: `\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{- \pagemark{} -}` should do the trick :-) read up on the fancy options of the package!

Comment: I spent an hour looking for this. Thanks a lottt:))